# Identify Phrases Not in Training Set (Unsupervised)

Tags: machine-learning, python, k-means, natural-language, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to train an unsupervised machine learning algorithm to learn a vocabulary and if it is given a word, it can predict how close that word is to what it already knows. Only issue is my approach will take weeks to finish.

Here is the use case:

Training Phrase Set:
- nike shoes
- adidas shoes
- durable water bottles
- best water bottles

I used KMeans and silhouette score to determine there are two clusters:

- Cluster 1: nike shoes, adidas shoes
- Cluster 2: durable water bottles, best water bottles

Then I used Gaussian Mixture to train the phrases based on the optimal number of clusters from the silhouette scores.

When I send a new keyword that fits poorly in the cluster I'd like to have a lot probability of being in any cluster. You can get this with scores from the GM:

- Great fits: nike shoe, nike sandal
- Poor fits: computer monitor, soft t-shirts

However, if I have 10,000 keywords and need to run through 9,999 KMeans / silhouette trials to find the optimal number of clusters, the program will run for an incredibly long amount of time.

Any thoughts on how to predict how similar a phrase is to a lexicon? I'd prefer to use a ML algorithm.

I've searched and cannot find any examples in Python. Any help would be much appreciated.